# Bootstrap 3 Fixed Top Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap 3 fixed top navigation bar. But when I decrease the browser screen size and click the button its not showing any links

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>    

<body>

    <!-- Creating a Fixed (top) Navigation Bar with Dropdown -->  
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>               
              </button>
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Exclusive</a>
            </div>     

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">                
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>                       

        </div>    
    </div>  
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

But on resizing and clicking the toggle button it doesn't display links

[image]

**I have included jquery files that are required.**

Comment: your code is working fine it might issue with including js       **https://jsfiddle.net/7ny02kjf/**

Comment: change your .js order - keep jquery first and bootstrap.js second ! + use only one bootstrap.js - either .min.js or normal .js

Answer (score 1):

You will get `script` error **`$ is undefined`** because the way you are loading scripts which is as below is wrong.

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!--Either keep this-->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script> <!--or this-->
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script><!--should come first-->
```

Before loading any `.js` files you need to load `jquery-*.js`

So ultimately you need

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

So you can either use `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js` but not both. That will create conflict!

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/y07utx6d/)**

Comment: Thanks brother , got it right. Jquery should be the first and then bootstrap js

Comment: Anytime..  Happy coding.. :)

Comment: @MahtabAlam Do not forget to mark it as answer if it helped!!

Answer (score 1):

**You have a mistake on your code.**

1. first jQuery.js.
   and, next bootstrap.js
2. change `<div class="navbar" ...></div>` to `<nav class="navbar" ...></nav>`

**[Result]**
https://jsfiddle.net/u2v1nLpb/3/

```
<body>

        <!-- Creating a Fixed (top) Navigation Bar with Dropdown -->  
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>               
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Exclusive</a>
                </div>     

                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                       

            </div>    
        </nav>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's **not** the **Error**. Its **Bootstrap 3 Responsive Page Feature**.
When You Open your page in **Small Screen or On Mobile Phones** then it will Automatically Adjust your **Template Page View**.

When you **Click** your **Right Icon** then You can see your **Links** there..

**I think this is the solution Which you Want:**

if you Want **appeared Links** when you Open your page on **small Devices**. then you **must** need to change **class-name** in your **HTML Page**.

instead of "**navbar-Collapse**" and "**Collapse**" use "**navbar-Expand**" and "**Expand**"

**Note:** please include your js file in a Priority Sequence. it will help you in future development.

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

my HTML code is here:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
</head> 

<body>
    <!-- Creating a Fixed (top) Navigation Bar with Dropdown -->  
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle " data-toggle="Expand" data-target=".navbar-Expand">
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>               
              </button>
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Exclusive</a>
            </div>     

            <div class="navbar-Expand Expand">                
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="text-center">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="text-center">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="text-center">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="text-center">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>                       

        </div>    
    </div> 
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

see the output image:

[image]